# The meaning of notation $[A : B]$ when $A$ and $B$ are matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

While reading an article [1], I encountered notation that I couldn't decipher: $[A : B]$, where $A$ and $B$ are both $n \times n$ real matrices. The following statement was also given (if that helps):

> If $[A : B]$ has full rank $a \in \ker A^T$ and $a \in \ker B^T$ implies $a = 0$.

What does $[A : B]$ mean?

---

[1]: Jesús Rodríguez and Kristen Kobylus Abernathy: On the solvability of nonlinear boundary value problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an [augmented matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix). It's the $n\times2n$ matrix you get from putting $A$ and $B$ next to one another and interpret it as a single matrix.